# How to postpone saving a file with curl

Tags: powershell, curl, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

I want to download several *zip* files by using some GET requests in Windows PowerShell through the curl.exe, but some of the response bodies are not *zip* but *json* files containing the link to the *zip* file.

So my original

`$(curl.exe -X GET -H $H1 $requestURL -o "C:\path\filename.zip")`

now needs to be something like

```
$jsonOrZip = $(curl.exe -X GET -H $H1 $requestURL)

if($jsonOrZip.count > 1000){
  (save $jsonOrZip as a zip file)
} else {
  $requestURL = (extract url from $jsonOrZip string to download zip file)
  $(curl.exe -X GET -H $H1 $requestURL -o "C:\path\filename.zip")
}
```

The conditional `$jsonOrZip.count > 1000` is the condition that I use to know if the body response is a *zip* file (count > 1000) or a *json* file (count < 1000)

I need to know how to **save $jsonOrZip as a zip file**. I did try the following

`$jsonOrZip | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\path\filename.zip'`

but I get a corrupted *zip* file.

Another way I could solve this problem is by repeating the previous request and outputting it as a *zip* file

`$(curl.exe -X GET -H $H1 $requestURL -o 'C:\path\filename.zip')`

but I don't want to download the same file twice (the *zip* files are very large files and I have many of them to download)

Is there any function more appropriate or another way to solve this issue?

Comment: Run `curl.exe -X GET -H $H1 $requestURL -o "C:\path\filename.zip"` then check saved file and conditionally rename?

Comment: It's an option. But how could I recheck (sorry but I am new to PS)? I want to do this based on file size. If it's low size then get the new url then request again.

Comment: Maybe `if ((Get-Item  "C:\path\filename.zip").Length -le 1000) {$jsonOrZip = Get-Content  "C:\path\filename.zip" -Raw; <extract …>}`